# BigBlueButton 2-3-dev html5client showing "404 not found" nginx error

Tags: bigbluebutton

Lately I have installed bbb 2.3 on my Ubuntu 18.04 VPN server. After a few road-bumps it installed and `bbb-conf --status` shows no error/warning.

```
<pre>
root@mydomain:~# bbb-conf --status
default
nginx —————————————————► [✔ - active]
freeswitch ————————————► [✔ - active]
redis-server ——————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-apps-akka —————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-fsesl-akka ————————► [✔ - active]
tomcat8 ———————————————► [✔ - active]
mongod ————————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-html5 —————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-webrtc-sfu ————————► [✔ - active]
kurento-media-server ——► [✔ - active]
etherpad ——————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-web ———————————————► [✔ - active]


root@mydomain:~# bbb-conf --check
default

BigBlueButton Server 2.3.0-beta-3 (1975)
                    Kernel version: 4.15.0
                      Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (64-bit)
                            Memory: 33554 MB
                         CPU cores: 8

/etc/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.properties (override for bbb-web)
/usr/share/bbb-web/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties (bbb-web)
       bigbluebutton.web.serverURL: https://bbb.mydomain.com
                defaultGuestPolicy: ALWAYS_ACCEPT
                 svgImagesRequired: true

/etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton (nginx)
                       server_name: bbb.mydomain.com
                              port: 80, [::]:80
                              port: 443 ssl

/opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/vars.xml (FreeSWITCH)
                       local_ip_v4: inet
                   external_rtp_ip: 1xx.xxx.xx.x7
                   external_sip_ip: 1xx.xxx.xx.x7

/opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles/external.xml (FreeSWITCH)
                        ext-rtp-ip: $${external_rtp_ip}
                        ext-sip-ip: $${external_sip_ip}
                        ws-binding: 1xx.xxx.xx.x7:5066
                       wss-binding: 1xx.xxx.xx.x7:7443

/usr/local/bigbluebutton/core/scripts/bigbluebutton.yml (record and playback)
                     playback_host: bbb.mydomain.com
                 playback_protocol: https
                            ffmpeg: 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1bbb2~18.04

/etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/sip.nginx (sip.nginx)
                        proxy_pass: 1xx.xxx.xx.x7
                          protocol: http

/usr/local/bigbluebutton/bbb-webrtc-sfu/config/default.yml (Kurento SFU)
                        kurento.ip: 1xx.xxx.xx.x7
                       kurento.url: ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
                    kurento.sip_ip: 1xx.xxx.xx.x7
                    localIpAddress: inet
               recordScreenSharing: true
                     recordWebcams: true
                  codec_video_main: VP8
               codec_video_content: VP8

/usr/share/meteor/bundle/programs/server/assets/app/config/settings.yml (HTML5 client)
                             build: 1588
                        kurentoUrl: wss://bbb.mydomain.com/bbb-webrtc-sfu
                  enableListenOnly: true
                    sipjsHackViaWs: true

/usr/share/bbb-web/WEB-INF/classes/spring/turn-stun-servers.xml (STUN Server)
                              stun: stun.l.google.com:19302

/etc/kurento/modules/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini (STUN Server)
                              stun: 172.217.212.127:19302


# Potential problems described below

# Warning: The API demos are installed and accessible from:
#
#    https://bbb.mydomain.com
#
# and
#
#    https://bbb.mydomain.com/demo/demo1.jsp
#
# These API demos allow anyone to access your server without authentication
# to create/manage meetings and recordings. They are for testing purposes only.
# If you are running a production system, remove them by running:
#
#    apt-get purge bbb-demo
</pre>
```

Calling API is also returning SUCCESS response, but the html5client, when running in browser is showing 404 not found error.
**API Response**
[image: API Response]
**HTML5CLIENT**
[image: HTML5CLIENT]

I have tried troubleshooting from the bbb docs itself but nothing changed. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: can you post the full url, generally there wil be an issue with the url

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @MozartLen - I updated to latest stable version and the issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

check this file to see if BigBlueButtonURL is correct and https:

```
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo/bbb_api_conf.jsp
```

(tomcat7 in the case of tomcat8 doesn't exist)